# SQL request with count() and position

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I've looking for answers but haven't found anything that I could apply to my table, or understand.

I've a table called `Vote` with 2 fields `idVotant` and `idVote` (`idVotant` is the guy who made the vote, and `idVote` is the guy for who he voted)

If I use this:

```
SELECT count(idVote) FROM Vote WHERE idVote=6
```

I get the number of votes that guy n°6 received.

If I use this:

```
SELECT idVote,count(idVote) AS votes FROM Vote GROUP BY idVote ORDER BY votes DESC
```

I get the list of all the guys and the number of votes they have.

Now, what I want to do is get the position of each guys, and of a specific one.
The guy n°6 is first because he got more votes, the guy n°2 is second.
And asking the position of a guy like which position is guy n°3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS position, u.idVote, u.votes
FROM (
    SELECT idVote, count(idVote) AS votes FROM Vote GROUP BY idVote ORDER BY votes DESC
) u,
(SELECT @rownum:=0) r
```

See the [demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e7435/1). I have basically wrapped your SQL query inside the `rownum` query

To find a particular person, use this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS position, u.idVote, u.votes
  FROM (
    SELECT idVote, count(idVote) AS votes FROM Vote GROUP BY idVote ORDER BY votes DESC
  ) u,
  (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
) ranked_vote WHERE idVote=6
```

Comment: Thanks, I just had to remove u.id and u.votes at the begining, and it worked well ^^ but cold you please explain it to me ? I don't understand the @rownum part and the u and r

Comment: and how can I get the position of a specific guy please ? like adding "WHERE idVote=6" I tryied but it doesn't work like that.

Comment: @user2377713 the `@rownum` part works like this: a new variable `rownum` is created and initialized with a value of 0 in the temporary table `r`. Table `r` is then joined with your query which is now named as table `u`. `rownum` variable is increase it by 1 for every record in the join of `u` and `r`.

Comment: I accepted it, but I can't upvote it, it said I need 15 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

**Try Following:**

```
 SELECT idVote,count(idVote) AS votes,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY count(idVote) desc)  AS Rank
       FROM Vote 
       GROUP BY idVote
       ORDER BY count(idVote) 
       DESC
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e7435/7)

Hope its helpful.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'idVote,count(idVote),ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY votes)  AS Rank,count(idVote) A' at line 1

Comment: you have tagged for both sql and mysql

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: (this one addresses tie votes)

```
 SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT idVote, Votes, CASE 
        WHEN @totalvotes = Votes THEN @rank 
        ELSE @rank := @rank + 1 
      END AS Ranking, @totalvotes := Votes  FROM
        (SELECT idVote, count(*) as Votes
         FROM Vote
         GROUP BY idVote ORDER BY Votes DESC) V
   JOIN (SELECT @rank:=0) r) VoteRanking
```

See my [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b1ee/60)

And if you want to select specific ranking let's say ranking no.2 just add :

```
 WHERE Ranking=2
```

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'row_number' in 'where clause'